# when i use npm start ,this error show up,how can i solve it?

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-03T11_19_56_985Z-debug-0.log

PS C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1> npm start

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1\package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-03T11_22_28_346Z-debug-0.log

how can i solve this in my react project

Comment: post your package.json file

Comment: `C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1/package.json` looks odd: might be the single `/` a problem here? Are you running `npm start` in the same directory as the package.json is?

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command once you enter the same directory where the package.json file exists if you cannot resolve the error share your folder structure please.

Answer (score -1):

Check the directory: Make sure that you are in the correct directory (C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1) where your React project is located. If you are in the wrong directory, navigate to the correct directory using the cd command. Also try avoid spaces in directory names (react-codes / react_codes would be a better fit)

Verify the package.json file: Ensure that the package.json file exists in the C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Desktop\react codes\code1 directory. If it is missing, you may need to create one using `npm init`.

Install dependencies: If the package.json file exists but the issue persists, it's possible that your dependencies are missing or not installed. `Run npm install.`

Please share your folder structure if this does not help.